# Breeze.js loadNavigationProperty with expand

Tags: javascript, breeze, navigation-properties

Is it possbible to call `loadNavigationProperty` with expanding the entities? Something like:

```
myGarage.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty('car.wheels');
```

Or is this only possible with a new query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use loadNavigationProperty with immediate nav properties (i.e. myGarage.car).

We'll update our documentation so there is no confusion.

Comment: Yes. You'd be better off issuing a new query with the multi-segment expand clause.

Answer (score 0):

Based on breeze source:

```
    function loadNavigationalProperty(entity, propertyName, forceReload, expand) {
        if (forceReload || !entity.entityAspect.isNavigationPropertyLoaded(propertyName)) {
            var navProperty = entity.entityType._checkNavProperty(propertyName);
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.fromEntityNavigation(entity, navProperty);
            if (expand) query = query.expand(expand);
            return manager.executeQuery(query).catch(queryFailed);
        } 
        return $q.resolve({ results: entity[propertyName] });
    }
```